# Using pyspark to read json file directly from a website

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

is it possible to use sqlContext to read a json file directly from a website?
for instance I can read file as such:

```
myRDD = sqlContext.read.json("sample.json")
```

but get I an error when I try something like this:

```
myRDD = sqlContext.read.json("http://192.168.0.13:9200/sample.json")
```

I'm using Spark 1.4.1
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible. Paths you use should point to either local file system or other file system supported by Hadoop. As long as `sample.json` has an expected format (single object per line) you can try something like this:

```
import json
import requests

r = requests.get("http://192.168.0.13:9200/sample.json")
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([json.loads(line) for line in r.iter_lines()])
```

Comment: I was wondering if a message queue system would come in handy. Afterward, the json will be treated as a stream with Spark. What do you think?

Comment: It could be an overkill but generally speaking makes sense.

Comment: I would depend on the size of the input data.

Comment: @eliasah Thats true. Another idea is to push request down to `mapPartitions` or `flatMap` where you can use generators. It would require a proper failure handling though and that may be tricky.